# No route found for custom REST resource

Tags: 8

I'm trying to create a custom REST GET resource for a specific node type, and I have the class created and enabled via the REST UI module settings (using the current 1.x-dev release so configs are generated w/o me having to manually create a routing.yml file). For reference, here's the class code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Custom Rest resource for video nodes.
 */

namespace Drupal\video_export\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a resource for database watchdog log entries.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "video_export_source",
 *   label = @Translation("Video Export Source"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/videos/feed/{site}"
 *   }
 * )
 */

class VideoExportResource extends ResourceBase {
  /**
   *  A curent user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
    * @param array $configuration
    *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
    * @param string $plugin_id
    *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
    * @param mixed $plugin_definition
    *   The plugin implementation definition.
    * @param array $serializer_formats
    *   The available serialization formats.
    * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    *   A logger instance.
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
    *   A current user instance.
  */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
    * Responds to GET requests.
    *
    * Returns a list of video nodes to be imported into the target site.
    *
    * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
    *   The response containing a list of bundle names.
    *
    * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 */
  public function get($site = NULL) {
    $response = ['message' => 'Hello, this is a rest service'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }
}
```

However, when I access my URL via `http://mysite/videos/feed/sourcesite?_format=xml`, all I get is this error:

> No route found for "GET /videos/feed/newsbusters"

and my debugger doesn't even hit my get() function. In reading the [RESTful Web Services API overview docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview) it appears that I might be missing the second part of the `uri_paths` setting in the class annotation. However, the example doesn't make sense to me for my use. if the canonical url is just `/videos/export/{site}` (where `{site}` is a parameter), what is the correct second part? Just `http://myite.com/videos/export`?

Or,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the REST UI module is just thought to change the content of the YAML files for the REST resources. It is up to the module correctly define the URL to use.

In your case, the annotation of the class should contains:

```
 uri_paths = {
   "canonical" = "/videos/feed/{site}",
   "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/videos/feed"
 }
```

I am not sure the placeholder makes any difference, but all the examples use `{id}`.

Comment: I don't understand the importance of the `https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create` path. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I'm wondering the same question as wonder95, what is the significance?

Comment: I think this somehow related to fake a bit the core implementation. Otherwise, the API will expect the request to use the /entity/{entity_type} endpoint.